# Can I use an Angular es5 controller with a new es6 service using babel and grunt?

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I want to start using ES6 (2015) in my Angular 1.3 + grunt stack without refactoring the entire existing ES5 code, (or switching grunt with other tool..) 
But when trying to use a new ES6 service from an "old" controller I'm getting following error,

" Cannot read property '1' of null
    at Function.annotate [as $$annotate] .... "

The babel configuration in grunt:

```
        babel: {
        options: {
            sourceMap: true,
            presets: ['es2015']
        },
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                src: '**/*.es6.js',
                dest: '.tmp/app',
                ext: '.es5.js'
            }]
        },
        test: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'test/spec',
                src: '{,*/}*.es6.js',
                dest: '.tmp/spec',
                ext: '.es5.js'
            }]
        }
    },
```

The service code:

```
class InfoService {
    constructor($http) {
      this.$http = $http;
    }

    getInfo() {
        console.log('getting');
        return this.$http.get('/backend/something/readAll');
    }
}

InfoService.$inject = ['$http'];

angular.module('app').service('Info', $http => InfoService($http));
```

The use in es5 controller:

```
angular.module('app').controller('SomeCtrl', 
function ComposerCtrl(Info) {
    Info.getInfo();
});
```

The transpiled ES5 InfoService was generated under .tmp/app (and I configured grunt watch to update changes while developing) so I wonder what am I doing wrong..

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten about `new`:

```
...
angular.module('app').service('Info', $http => new InfoService($http))
```

In this case, angular will not benefit from `$inject` property and you will need to ng-annotate your code, as it solves to:

```
angular.module('app').service('Info', function($http) { return new InfoService($http); });
```

The simpler solution it to replace service definition with:

```
angular.module('app').service('Info', InfoService);
```

Angular's DI will use `$inject` property and add `new` operator for you.

It is worth noting, that TypeScript users had the same problem:
[How can I define an AngularJS service using a TypeScript class that doesn't pollute the global scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447886/how-can-i-define-an-angularjs-service-using-a-typescript-class-that-doesnt-poll)

**EDIT:**

It is possible, that you are using wrong controller expression (for example unclosed `ng-controller` attribute:

```
 <div .... ng-controller="SignupFormController as signupFormCtrl>
```

This messes up angular and leads to this error message on older versions of angular (1.3).

More info about issue:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10875

Comment: Thanks for the help!! I'm gonna try it and really hope to vote up your answer

Comment: Also, this code `.service('Info', $http => new InfoService($http))` is incorrect because an arrow can't be a constructor.

Comment: @estus an arrow is just a way to say - take $http as param and return new InfoService which its constructor uses the $http param.....

Comment: Unfortunately I even when added the 'new' or tried the other way with 'ngInject' annotation and just  'angular.module('app').service('Info', InfoService);' it didn't help :( I'll read the link post maybe it will help

Comment: @lironn `service` instantiates a function with `new`. Arrows can't be newed, using it there is an error. The only reason why this may work is because an arrow is  transpiled to normal function with Babel. The same code will fail on native ES6. Any way, the answer is correct.

Comment: @estus appreciate your help, I will check it out, but I actually based my poc on something that works (https://github.com/twintags/angular-es6-demo/blob/master/app/scripts/services/info.js)

Comment: my ng-controller expressions are all closed, just verified, I suspect the issue is on my grunt configuration when serving the files, maybe something in the connect task or so, that's the lead I'm checking right now..

Answer (score 0):

So I've found a way to make it work but I don't like it so much..
I configured the babel to dist the files at the same place my *.es6.js files and updated the index.html so Angular will load the es5 transpiled file (InfoService.js), and when I debug I do it on the es6 file (I guess it relates to the sourceMap)

```
        babel: {
        options: {
            sourceMap: true,
            presets: ['es2015']
        },
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                src: '**/*.es6.js',
                ext: '.js'
            }]
        },
```